# Is it possible to get textbox with Kendo Dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

This is how I am creating my dropdownlist via `data-bind` property and datasource to read the data from the given url.

```
<input class="js-editable" id="PlacedBy" name="PlacedBy" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { value: PlacedBy, optionLabel: '@General.OptionLabel_Select', dataSource: {transport: { read: {url: '/api/common/GetEnabledUsers', data: {text:''} } } } }" />
```

Now the problem is,  our system has setting where the dropdown can be disabled and it turns into an kendo autocomplete function. Here, users are able to add values of their own. When the setting for dropdown is turned on again, the custom values added by users are gone. I have checked the view model, the value is coming from the controller to the view but due to this kendo-data binding It is not displayed because it doesn't match the set of options provided in the dropdown list.

**Note: To confirm the value is coming to view I turned this DDL to textbox and the value was populating there. Also, I checked the viewBag where the value was stored and its there as well.**

Solutions I have tried:

1. I saw one of the old posts here where they used  `dataBound: onDataBound` to add that custom value into DDL after datasource has finished reading the data and created the function like:
   In my case

**Html**:

```
<input class="js-editable" id="PlacedBy" name="PlacedBy" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { value: PlacedBy, optionLabel: '@General.OptionLabel_Select', dataSource: {transport: { read: {url: '/api/common/GetEnabledUsers', data: {text:''} } } }, dataBound:onDataBound }" />
```

**JS Function**:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
        e.sender.dataSource.add({ text: "xxxxx", value: "xxxxx" });
    }
```

This function didn't work for me as I got `[object][object]` error on the dropdown list and `dataBound`  wasn't stopping after adding a value. I looked for function to stop the dataBound after first instance but failed.

So, is there any way we can turn a kendo dropdown into textbox dropdown where it allows custom values to display until the dropdown is clicked.
Thank you for any help.
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout and a flag to stop your code from adding another item when onDataBound triggers again after the add:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    if (!suppress) {
        suppress = true;
        e.sender.dataSource.add({ text: "xxxxx", value: "xxxxx" });
        setTimeout(function () {
            suppress = false;
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that will fix the [object][object] problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have fixed the object object issue but the problem with stopping the function after data adds up into the source isn't fixed.  e.sender.dataSource.add({ data: 'xxxxxx' }); fixed it.